# Javascript Extract from substring regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I don't have any experience with Regex. How do I extract the value of FieldInternalName from a string like below? Need only the value without quotes.

```
var idString = '<!--  FieldName="App" FieldInternalName="Application" FieldType="SPFieldLookup" -->';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very easy to set up a simple expression that will "capture" the contents of `FieldInternalName`:

```
<!--.*?\bFieldInternalName="([^"]+)".*?-->
```

[***Demo***](http://regex101.com/r/iM4lZ2/1)

---

This expression works by looking for:

- `<!--`
- 0+ characters (`.*?`)
- `FieldInternalName="` (preceded by a word boundary,`\b`, so that you don't match something like `FakeFieldInternalName="`)
- 1+ non-`"` characters (`[^"]+`)
- `"`
- 0+ characters (`.*?`)
- `-->`

---

Using [`RegExp.prototype.exec()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec), we can extract the contents of this match:

```js
var idRegex = /<!--.*?\bFieldInternalName="([^"]+)".*?-->/,
    idString = '<!--  FieldName="App" FieldInternalName="Application" FieldType="SPFieldLookup" -->';

var matches = idRegex.exec(idString);
console.log(matches[1]);
```

```html
<script src="https://getfirebug.com/firebug-lite-debug.js"></script>
```

Comment: Didn't know there was such a tool with so much detail.Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

would something like this work for ya?

```
var idString = '<!--  FieldName="App" FieldInternalName="Application" FieldType="SPFieldLookup" -->';
var fieldInternalName = idString.match(/FieldInternalName="(.*?)"/i)[1];
alert(fieldInternalName);
```